# Facing error while Deploying winui windows application

Tags: windows, winui-3, winui, windows-application-driver

```
This app package’s publisher certificate could not be verified. Contact your system administrator or the app developer to obtain a new app package with verified certificates. The root certificate and all immediate certificates of the signature in the app package must be verified (0x800B010A)
```

This was the error I am facing during installation of windows application in another device

Tried Deploying application in another device

Comment: The error is quite clear. The package is signed with a certificate and the certificate publisher cannot be verified. It probably means the certificate is not installed locally, or it's not signed by a trusted certificate authority. See here for example where the signing certificate is installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-create-a-package-signing-certificate#remarks

Comment: I have tired this and I'm facing the same error here @SimonMourier